# Click event not registering on div element (jQuery/HTML/CSS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, click

This is my game: (i can't post images yet so I have to explain with words)
This is a Connect 4 game.
Imagine 7 div columns.
The 7 columns have 6 div chip objects stacked in each column element.
(7x6 grid with 42 chips)

- I put each chip (each black circle) as a div object prepended into each column container.
- that is... each .columncontainer div has nested under it a bunch of .chip div elements. (they're the chips/circles)

**What I want:**
I want to be able to click a specific chip object (they're div's.. the black circles) and I want ONLY that one to turn full black. (default opacity I set to 0.5)

**This is the code I have:**

```
$(document).ready(function colorSelectionListener(){
$(".columncontainer").children().click(function() {
    window.alert("clicked!");
    $(this).css("opacity",1);
});
```

**What's actually happening:** When I click on ANY of the chip objects... NOTHING happens. I can't click the chips at all.

**What I can do:** To test if I can click something I made the alert "clicked!" In this way I am able to click the columncontainers. I am also able to retrieve the index of the column div inside it when I print out the index of 'this', like so:

```
window.alert($(this).index());
```

instead of the 'clicked!' message. It gives me 6...which doesn't make sense... because 6 is the last element inside columncontainer which is .column. (0-5 elements must be the chips after I prepend them right?)

**What I tried:** I tried making the .click with the chip objects themselves. (the class attached to every chip object is '.chip') Did not work. (Click was not registering... but I think that's another problem)

Can someone enlighten me?

EDIT 1:
**Mini Recreation of Problem**
https://jsfiddle.net/9z916z2u/65/

If anyone could help me I would really really appreciate it! I'm having so much fun coding this right now but this is annoying :/ I learnt jQuery/Javascript around 3 days ago, so I'm not that good. (I have coded in Java/Python before though)

Comment: Your html code posted would allow to get a better picture of the problem

Comment: @KirillSlatin Okay! I've made an update to my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.columncontainer .cheap').click(function(){
    $(this).css('opacity', 1)
})
```

Or, if you want to add `.cheap` blocks dynamically, you can use this variant:

```
$('.columncontainer').on('click', '.cheap', function(){
    $(this).css('opacity', 1)
})
```

Comment: I tried both! It's still not working.
  
`$(document).ready(function colorSelectionListener(){
    $('.columncontainer').on('click','.chip', function(){
        $(this).css('opacity',1);
    });
});`

Comment: Can you reproduce the error in jsfiddle? There is my example http://jsfiddle.net/9z916z2u/3/

Comment: Arkihpov Yes! That's what I want! But my chip divs are not in my html code... they are added in later by jQuery using .prepend. (I have a special mode button... when it is pressed.. the chips are put in)

Comment: Okay I'll reproduce it and give you a link! Hold on.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/9z916z2u/7/ <-- That's how I did it in my code. But it's not working I don't know why

Comment: fixed two typos in your example and now it works https://jsfiddle.net/9z916z2u/10/ :)

Comment: Wow thanks! That works amazing! That's exactly what I want! :) But I still can't get that to work in my code :/

Comment: I'll try reproducing a small version of it... thanks so much for your help ! :)

Comment: If you publish your non-working code at some hosting, we can look what's wrong with it. Or you can try fully reproduce it in jsfiddle, with the incorrect behavior. It's too hard to figure out what is the problem with a non-working code without this code itself :)

Comment: A bunch of things: 1. If you want to add circles to the column, you should change this selector http://prntscr.com/6asodl. 2. The celector for `cheap:click` event should  point to the container, not `.cheap` itself http://prntscr.com/6asojj 3. We should call e#stopPropagation() to prevent the calling of the first `click` listener, which adds new circles http://prntscr.com/6asork. 4. And I removed `position: absolute` from the css just to see circles one above the other. Final example https://jsfiddle.net/9z916z2u/66/

Comment: YOU ARE A GOD! OH MY GOD. THANK YOU SO MUCH I LEARNT SO MUCH THANKS TO YOU :) <3 <3

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".columncontainer > childElement").click(function() {
        window.alert("clicked!");
        $(this).css("opacity",1);
     }    
});
```

replace child element with d tag or the class of the childred of .columncontainer

Comment: Still can't click it! I'm only able to click the .columncontainer. 
Also, the .columncontainer has a .column inside it. Does that matter? Because I'm able to click that too.... except the chips. (Chips are not in original HTML... i add them later)

Comment: I got it fixed by the previous commentor! No worries! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Posted code in JSFiddle needs some adjustments to work. I've modified the event subscription to match late binding (according to Anatoliy Arkhipov).

```
$('.columncontainer').on('click', '.cheap', function(){
```

Instead of

```
$('.cheap').on('click', function(){
```

And removed `position: relative` for the `.column` class. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/9z916z2u/80/) is how the code looks now and it works in Chrome and FF.

However, I consider the answer to be not consistent (why does `position: relative` prevented binding?) and maybe masters of css can explain that.